# Detect position of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, numbered-list

I'm coding a text adventure, and I have created a system where the user can observe an area and the objects in the area.

For example, a user can observe an area as:

"A bland, quiet desert. You can see a **cat**, a **mouse**, and a **broom**."

It creates a list of the items with a number before each using a for loop.

1. Take or observe cat
2. Take or observe mouse

etc.

I want to know how I can assign a number to each dict entry as it appears in the text.

`{"cat":1, "mouse":1, "broom":1}`

The value for each key is how many instances of the object appears. How do I make my code allow for each key to have a value ASIDE from its dictionary value to be able to be referenced in order?

The user should be able to type the number of his/her response corresponding to the numbered list. If they choose '1' they choose to observe the cat, and that can change based on what "object number 1" would be in that dictionary, which changes based on what area the user is currently in.

If the user is in a dark cave, maybe "object number 1" in that SAME dictionary is changed to "dog". The user should be able to choose "1" and observe a DOG instead of a CAT...

So how can I detect which key is in what position of a dictionary?

Comment: does the user define the dictionary or is it initialized by the programmer?

Comment: Dict entries don't *have* positions. If you want to represent an ordering of the keys, it's usually best to track that separately. There's `collections.OrderedDict`, but that tracks order by its own rules that you don't have much control over.

Comment: or you could look at [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: You could also use tuples as the value of your dictionary and store order on one of the values and instance on the other

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different kinds of data here. One is a long-term set of traits (how many instances of the object appear) and the other is a very transient index only used by the user for a menu selection. Delegate that second use case to a function that does the prompting. It can use a simple list that you pass to the function and figure out the indexing itself.

```
item_database = {"cat":1, "mouse":1, "broom":1}

def multiprompt(base, *items):
    """Prompt for a list of items and return the item selected"""
    while 1:
        for index, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            print("{}. {} {}".format(index, base, item))
        try:
            choice = int(input("Select number: "))
            if choice < 1 or choice > len(items):
                raise ValueError()
            return items[choice-1]
        except ValueError:
            print("Error, try again")

choice = multiprompt("Take or observe", "cat", "mouse", "broom")
print("You chose {} which as count {}".format(choice,
    item_database[choice]))
```